# DevExpress GridViewBandColumn pass C# variable to the Caption

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

```
<dx:GridViewBandColumn Caption="My Title" >
```

Instead of hard coding "My Title", I want the caption to read as a string variable from my aspx.cs file.  That variable will change over time, so the caption needs to update dynamically.

So for example:

```
//C#
String var = "My Title";

//ASPx
<dx:GridViewBandColumn Caption=var >
```

How do I do this?

I can't create a label in the GridViewBandColumn and pass the variable that way.

Comment: Why not set the value in the CodeBehind?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can make a variable **protected** or **public** in your C# class file to allow it be visible for your .aspx page as below:</strike>

//C#

> ```
> protected string myValue = "My Title";
> ```

and in your .aspx file you can read that value like this:

> ```
> <dx:GridViewBandColumn Caption="<%: myValue %>" />
> ```

---

Apparently the DevExpress doesn't allow inline code on this control so I have to update the  the code above to the following solution:

//aspx.cs

> ```
> Grid.Columns["MyCol"].Caption = "my title";
> ```

//.aspx

> ```
> <dx:GridViewBandColumn Name="MyCol" Caption="" />
> ```

and the client side solution would be changing the caption using JQuery by its own caption name:
//.aspx

> ```
> <dx:GridViewBandColumn Caption="myValue" />
> ```

//jquery

> $("td:contains('myValue')").text("My Title");

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried declaring myValue as both public and protected in my C# class file. The Caption is displaying as <%: myValue %> in both cases

Comment: on your code behind try to change the Caption rather than changing on your .aspx file then. something like gridName.Caption = "My Title";

Comment: No, thats the whole point of this question...  The caption changes based on other dynamic things. I need to pass it a variable.

Comment: Ok, because DevExpress doesn't let you to use inline code on your .aspx file, you have two choices, one is you doing that on your page-load code behind and the second would be JavaScript/JQuery on client side. then you need to change the value there. let me know if you are not sure how to do it on JavaScript

Comment: Hi Ali. If DevExpress doesnt allow that, than your above answer is wrong..? Am I missing something? It doesnt have to be the Caption, but I need to display a C# string variable's value inside the GrideViewBandColumn. How can I do this? Can you show me a JS solution?